# How to refresh or update a fragment after deleting from the database

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am new to android development, and i'm trying to build a simple hymn book, 
I'm using bottom navigation, i use fragments on each tab to display numbers and titles of each hymn.
In my favourite fragments i have a list of favourite songs displayed using recycler view fetch from the database.
I use on long click listener to delete songs from the favorite table in the database, but any time i delete a
song my favorite fragment doesn't get refreshed or undated with current items. Please, how can I refresh or update
my favourite fragment anytime i delete a song. thank you!

'''Favourite Adapter''

```
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import static android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE;

public class FavouriteAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FavouriteAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private Context favContext;
    private ArrayList<String> favNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> favTitles  = new ArrayList<>();

    public FavouriteAdapter(Context favContext, ArrayList<String> favNumbers, ArrayList<String> favTitles) {
        this.favContext = favContext;
        this.favNumbers = favNumbers;
        this.favTitles = favTitles;
    }

    @Override
    public FavouriteAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.favourite_list_items, parent, false);

        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final FavouriteAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        holder.textViewFavNum.setText(favNumbers.get(position));
        holder.textViewFavTitle.setText(favTitles.get(position));
        final String hymn_no = favNumbers.get(position);
        holder.itemView.setTag(favNumbers.get(position));

        holder.favParentLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i;
                i = new Intent(view.getContext(), Songs.class);
                i.putExtra("numId", favNumbers.get(position));
                i.putExtra("titleName", favTitles.get(position));
                favContext.startActivity(i);

            }
        });


      holder.favParentLayout.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(final View view) {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext())
                        .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                        .setTitle("Are you sure?")
                        .setMessage("Do you want to delete from favorites?")
                        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int which) {


                                try{

                                    SQLiteDatabase favHymns = favContext.openOrCreateDatabase("Songs", MODE_PRIVATE, null);

                                    favHymns.execSQL("DELETE FROM favorites where hymnNum = '"+hymn_no+"'");

                                    Toast.makeText(favContext.getApplicationContext(), "hymn deleted ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                }catch(Exception e){
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }



                            }




                        })

                        .setNegativeButton("No", null)
                        .show();


                return true;


            }


        });


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return favNumbers.size();

    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position){
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position){
        return position;
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView textViewFavNum;
        public TextView textViewFavTitle;
        RelativeLayout favParentLayout;
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            textViewFavNum = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewFavNum);
            textViewFavTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewFavTitle);
            favParentLayout  =  (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.favParentLayout);
        }
    }
}

'''favourite fragment'''

    import android.app.FragmentManager;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
    import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.logging.Handler;

    import static android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE;


    /**
     * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
     */
    public class Favourites extends Fragment {


        private RecyclerView recyclerView;
        private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
        private ArrayList<String> favSongNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
        private ArrayList<String> favSongTitles  = new ArrayList<>();
        private TextView favMessage;



        public Favourites() {
            // Required empty public constructor
        }

        View view;
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            if(view == null) {
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_favourites, container, false);
                favMessage = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.favMessage);
                recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.favRecyclerView);
                //  adapter.setHasStableIds(true);


                Toast.makeText(this.getActivity(), "Long press to delete hymns from favorites", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                initFavSongs();

            }


            return view;
        }

        private void initFavSongs(){



            try{

                favMessage.setText("");

                SQLiteDatabase favHymns = this.getActivity().openOrCreateDatabase("Songs", MODE_PRIVATE, null);

                Cursor c = favHymns.rawQuery("SELECT  hymnNum, hymnTitle FROM favorites", null);

                int hymnNumIndex = c.getColumnIndex("hymnNum");
                int hymnTitleIndex = c.getColumnIndex("hymnTitle");

                if(c.moveToFirst()) {

                    while (c != null) {

                        favSongNumbers.add(Integer.toString(c.getInt(hymnNumIndex)) + ". ");
                        favSongTitles.add(" " + c.getString(hymnTitleIndex));

                        c.moveToNext();
                    }

                }else{
                    favMessage.setText("Oops!No favorite songs added yet.");
                }


            }catch (Exception e){

                e.printStackTrace();

            }


            initRecyclerView();
        }

        private void initRecyclerView(){

            adapter = new FavouriteAdapter(this.getActivity(), favSongNumbers, favSongTitles);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this.getActivity()));
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass a listener to the adapter and invoke it at the time of item delete from database. Then update your list and as well as your adapter.Like this way:

First create a listener:

```
public interface UpdateListener {

        void onValueChangedListener();
    }
```

Initialize the listener in Adapter class that comes from fragment.

```
private UpdateListener updateListener;

     public FavouriteAdapter(Context favContext, ArrayList<String> favNumbers, ArrayList<String> favTitles,UpdateListener updateListener ) {
            this.favContext = favContext;
            this.favNumbers = favNumbers;
            this.favTitles = favTitles;
    this.updateListener=updateListener;

        }


    holder.favParentLayout.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(final View view) {
                    new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext())
                            .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                            .setTitle("Are you sure?")
                            .setMessage("Do you want to delete from favorites?")
                            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int which) {


                                    try{

                                        SQLiteDatabase favHymns = favContext.openOrCreateDatabase("Songs", MODE_PRIVATE, null);

                                        favHymns.execSQL("DELETE FROM favorites where hymnNum = '"+hymn_no+"'");

                                        Toast.makeText(favContext.getApplicationContext(), "hymn deleted ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
// when any item delete from database notify the fragment through this 
  //  listener for updating your adapter
    updateListener.onValueChangedListener();


                                    }catch(Exception e){
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }


                                }


                            })

                            .setNegativeButton("No", null)
                            .show();


                    return true;


                }


            });
```

// this method is needed for updating your adapter

```
public void update(ArrayList<String> favNumbers, ArrayList<String> favTitles){
this.favNumbers = favNumbers;
                this.favTitles = favTitles;
}
```

Implement the listener in your fragment and reinitialize your list.

```
public class Favourites extends Fragment implements UpdateListener { 

    private void initRecyclerView(){
// pass listener
        adapter = new FavouriteAdapter(this.getActivity(), favSongNumbers, favSongTitles,this);

    }

private void updateFavSongs(){

favSongNumbers.clear;
favSongTitles.clear;



            try{

                favMessage.setText("");

                SQLiteDatabase favHymns = this.getActivity().openOrCreateDatabase("Songs", MODE_PRIVATE, null);

                Cursor c = favHymns.rawQuery("SELECT  hymnNum, hymnTitle FROM favorites", null);

                int hymnNumIndex = c.getColumnIndex("hymnNum");
                int hymnTitleIndex = c.getColumnIndex("hymnTitle");

                if(c.moveToFirst()) {

                    while (c != null) {

                        favSongNumbers.add(Integer.toString(c.getInt(hymnNumIndex)) + ". ");
                        favSongTitles.add(" " + c.getString(hymnTitleIndex));

                        c.moveToNext();
                    }

                }else{
                    favMessage.setText("Oops!No favorite songs added yet.");
                }


            }catch (Exception e){

                e.printStackTrace();

            }
         adapter.update(favSongNumbers,favSongTitles);
         adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

        }
    @Override
        public void onValueChangedListener(){
                    updateFavSongs();

    }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you sir for your answer. But adapter.update(favSongNumbers, favSongTitles) there is an error message with the update method, that cannot resolve method update. What should I do. Thank you!

Comment: @DanielNaanchin have you added an update method in the adapter?

Comment: Yes, I have. However, I commented the update method in my fragment and it's working. When I delete an item now it refreshes my fragment. Thank you.

Comment: Sir, I have an activity called songs, where I add items to my favorite table in my database, but anytime I add songs as favorite, it doesn't display in the favorite fragment, I will have to start the app again before I can see the items added. I once used activity to show favorite songs and it work perfectly, but not with fragments. Thank you so much for your help and i'm sorry if  my questions sounds foolish.

Comment: you need to update your fragment data list through the listener.Accept the answer if it's solved your problem